# Missing fuse cause of no A/C?

Tags: ac, hyundai, fuse, accent

2011 Hyundai Accent

I don't know much about cars, so I'd like someone to tell me if this missing fuse could be causing the AC to not activate. It's already been to a mechanic, so I assume they checked, but I'd like a second opinion.

[image]

Then according to [this link](https://fuse-box.info/hyundai/hyundai-accent-mc-2007-2011-fuses-and-relay) A/CON #2 (the missing fuse) is for the A/C Control Module and the fuse next to it (currently there) is for the A/Con Relay. Once I saw that I decided I'd try to use the horn fuse, which is the correct size, but the fuse was loose when I put it in the A/CON #2 slot. That's when I noticed the metal connector that the horn slot has was not present for the A/CON #2 slot. Some of the other slots are empty as well, so I'm wondering if this one was always missing or if the metal connector may have been damaged when someone tried changing the fuse. If this fuse, and it's connector, are supposed to be there for the AC how difficult would it be to fix? And if this needs to be done by a mechanic what would be a reasonable price?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What did the mechanic say about this issue? If the car is equipped with a/c, the fuse might have been removed by a previous owner because, for example, the fuse kept blowing. That would mean the missing fuse isn't the _cause_ of the a/c not working, but that _something else_ in the a/c system has failed.

Comment: I would rule out the common things that cause A/C systems to fail before chasing this. I would find it very unlikely that a fuse socket would be missing (for any reason). Have you checked if there's pressure in system? Does the cooling fan turn on when you activate the air conditioner?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I believe the mechanic tried replacing some kind of temperature sensor. This car was bought new and the A/C was working last summer. Although, the climate control unit was replaced during the winter, so I'm wondering if maybe the A/C button on that is not working. I was unable to find a diagram for that to test it.

Comment: @masospaghetti I have not checked the pressure in the system (I'm guessing I don't have the tool to do it). Where would I find the cooling fan to check it?

Comment: The radiator cooling fan should still turn on when the A/C is activated even if the A/C doesn't work. That would indicate a low refrigerant problem, or bad compressor, or some other issue, but that the electronics are in order.

Comment: @masospaghetti thank you for the reply. The radiator cooling fans do not turn on when the A/C is activated. Do you know where I could find a diagram to check the climate control panel pins?